# I want contents of file in array index , please find example below

Tags: node.js, automation, fs

```
  // fs.readFile(file, [encoding], [callback]);
  // converting file and storing it in an array
  var fileRefer = fs.readFileSync('LoginID\\Creds.txt').toString().split("\n");
  for (f in fileRefer) {
    let i = fileRefer[f];
    const [, , , , id, , pw,] = i.split(" "); //pipe sep. |
    // console.log(id,pw);
    let username = id;
    let password = pw;
```

Example- Date: 2021-11-08 17:01:33|LoginID: pvgA1248|Password: Root@123
So , what i want is till date it should be 0th index , till loginID 1st and so on..
Please help me to achieve the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you right but you want to split all values per line in a array?

like this:

```js
let str = "Date: 2021-11-08 17:01:33|LoginID: pvgA1248|Password: Root@123";

let result = str.split('|').reduce((a,v) => {
  v.split(': ').forEach(s=>a.push(s));
  return a;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```